# snap install of Viber on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux produces permission denied error

Tags: permission-denied, viber, snap

I have tried two different Viber packages available through snap, viber-unofficial.viber and viber-mtd.viber. Both packages produce the exact same error about WebEngine resources not found

```
sh: 1: xdg-mime: not found
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /snap/viber-unofficial/37/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /snap/viber-unofficial/37/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
[557326:557326:1013/081811.896484:FATAL:credentials.cc(155)] Check failed: NamespaceUtils::DenySetgroups(). : Permission denied
#0 0x7f5a59d4d11e base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7f5a59d5dbde logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x7f5a59d5de99 logging::ErrnoLogMessage::~ErrnoLogMessage()
#3 0x7f5a5aa4ff7c sandbox::(anonymous namespace)::SetGidAndUidMaps()
#4 0x7f5a5aa505d5 sandbox::Credentials::CanCreateProcessInNewUserNS()
#5 0x7f5a599c0de5 content::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#6 0x7f5a59673314 content::BrowserMainLoop::EarlyInitialization()
#7 0x7f5a59677190 content::BrowserMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#8 0x7f5a5947cd19 QtWebEngineCore::WebEngineContext::WebEngineContext()
#9 0x7f5a5947e135 QtWebEngineCore::WebEngineContext::current()
#10 0x7f5a5941b931 QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::defaultContext()
#11 0x7f5a6258c618 QQuickWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()
#12 0x0000006ac8bf ApplicationPrivate::preRunningInitialization()
#13 0x0000006a6504 ViberApplication::start()
#14 0x00000067e25b ViberMain()
#15 0x7f5a56403840 __libc_start_main
#16 0x0000004d7047 <unknown>

Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /snap/viber-unofficial/37/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /snap/viber-unofficial/37/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
```

I have looked at the permissions of the various directories and I don't see anything obvious other than everything in the snap package is all owned by root/root and the regular user trying to actually run the viber app does not have any write permission into these directories.